# Having issues with w/auto-populating last search result on my html form page when hitting refresh, using only javascript and local storage

Tags: javascript

I want to rerun the search or populate the results as if the user never left.
So I visit the page, search for cats and get some results based on cats. I close the tab, come back later, and rather than find myself on a fresh page that has no results, I’m provided with the results from my last search. I am only allowed to use Javascript and local storage to achieve this. Here is my JS file:

```
var search = document.getElementById('searchTerm');

if(!localStorage.getItem('input')) {
    populateStorage();                    
}


// To set the event to listen to
const form = document.querySelector('.js-search-form');

// To listen when user hits submit or press enter
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

//  Start of the query string
const base = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?include_adult=false&page=1&`;

// Extension of the query string
const searchTerm = document.querySelector('#searchTerm').value;
const language = `en-US&`;
const api_key = `7ab3cb18b4ad4a07bbd8bb01acfa7091`;

// The complete build of the url
const url = `${base}query=${searchTerm}&language=${language}api_key=${api_key}`;

// The get method
const option = {
    method: 'GET'
}

// Stops the default action
e.preventDefault()


fetch(url)

  //Parse data
  .then( response => {
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.json()
    } else {
        throw response
    }
})

 // Do something with data
  .then( data => {

    console.log(data)



// Output results
let resultElement = '';

    if(data.results.length > 1) {
        resultElement += `
                        <h2><span>Results for ${searchTerm}</span></h2>
                        <section class="js-search-results clearfix">
                        `;

        if(data.results) {

            data.results.forEach(function(results){

            resultElement += `<article class="item">
                             <div class="container">
                             <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${results.poster_path}"/>
                             <div class="content">`;
            if(results.title.length > 17) {
               resultElement += `<h3>${results.title.substr(0,17)}...</h3>`; 
            } else {
                resultElement += `<h3>${results.title}</h3>`;             
              }

            resultElement += `<p>Released: ${results.release_date}</p>`;
            resultElement += `</div>
                              </div>
                              </article>`;
        });

        resultElement += `</section>`;

        populateStorage()

    } else {
        resultElement += '<p class="no-results">No results</p>';
    }

    document.querySelector('.js-search-results').innerHTML = resultElement;
}     

})

.catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
    }) 
})

function populateStorage() {
    localStorage.setItem('searchTerm', document.getElementById('searchTerm').value);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- EDIT -

You are calling `localStorage.getItem('input');` but you are saving the local storage item as `searchTerm` please make these names consistent with one another

you either need to change `localStorage.getItem('input')`

TO

`localStorage.getItem('searchTerm');`

OR

change `localStorage.setItem('searchTerm', document.getElementById('searchTerm').value)`

TO

`localStorage.setItem('input', document.getElementById('searchTerm').value)`

-Edit-

Assuming that this is wrapped in a document ready function, update your initial check of storage to look like this...

```
var search = document.getElementById('searchTerm');
 //This assumes that you corrected your getItem to reference 'searchTerm'
if(!localStorage.getItem('searchTerm')) {

    populateStorage();                    
}
else {

    search.value = localStorage.getItem('searchTerm');
}
```

Your code never makes a call to actually populate that field so this should fix that.

Comment: Thanks so much for that! That fixed with saving it properly. However, I can't still get it to automatically load on my html page when I hit refresh.

Comment: I will update this answer with something that might help

Comment: Perfect that worked! The search term is saved and auto-populates into the input field on my search query form. Thanks so much! However, I'm a beginner with JS, so not sure then how I would not only have it auto-populate the search term, but also populate the search results as well. So for instance, I search for cats, I get results of cats....I would then close out of the page or hit refresh, I would want it to show the search term and also still show the results of the cats, it's as if I never left the page.

Comment: And as To populate the last results you could follow the same format as the search term. Upon a successful request you could set the response to a new local storage item ex: `searchResults` and then on page load, just like you are checking for the term, you could also check for results, and if results are available then you would use the same if statement under where you output results. Except instead of checking the length of data.results from your request you would check localStorage.getItem("searchResults"). If you dont understand I can post an example.

Comment: Ok perfect! Thanks so much! Truly appreciate it! I'm also new to stack overflow. How do I mark this as answered.

Comment: Sorry was trying to figure it out, but getting a null for the value, for my key "searchResults'. I know I'm doing something wrong. Can you please provide an example?